# ntsysv: error reading info for service °8B@h@@

Tags: linux, centos

When I try to start `ntsysv`, I get teh following error:

```
error reading info for service °8B@h@@: Invalid argument
```

No, that's no copy paste, issue... that's exactly what it looks like. What is that service?

Answer (score 1):

ntsysv appears to interrogate the /etc/init.d directory for services. When I had an empty file named res in there I received "error reading info for service res: Invalid argument", removed res and everything fine.

so I expect you've a file named "°8B@h@@" in etc/init.d/ therefore:-

error reading info for service °8B@h@@: Invalid argument